# SAS ods output: axis labels too condensed

Tags: sas, sas-ods

I am trying to output some plots (of cumulative incidence functions made by using `proc gplot`) with SAS 9.2 but somehow the letters of the axis labels keep to stay condensed, sort of covering each other. I would attach a picture with the problem but I do not have enough reputations to do so...

I have tried to reset all the options by executing:

```
goptions reset=all;
```

but it did not help much. If I set `ftext` to a different font type, the error(?) does not disappear. I would like to make .rtf outputs. Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Do you mean that the axis labels overlap, ie, one bar's label overlaps a second bar's label?

Comment: Hi Joe, I mean I have an axis label like "Follow-up period" and in that label 'F' covers 10% of 'o' then 'o' covers another 10% of 'l' etc. They are somehow merged onto each other.

Comment: What driver are you using to do the plot?

Comment: Also, could you create a small example of the gplot code, perhaps using SASHELP.PRDSALE or a similar dataset, so we can see exactly what you're doing?

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks a lot for the help, I did not have the time to do what you asked me to do (the program consisted of a macro-chain and I should have rewritten a lot of things). But, as you mentioned it in your second comment, the problem was, that among the goptions there were not specified any devices to make the plot. After I chose the `device=PNG` option my labels were cured. :-) Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: Brilliant, i'll post it as an answer then, even though it wasn't reaally intended to be :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your graphics device options.  Changing to `device=PNG` or `device=JPG` may help resolve this issue.